# Sort by Last name in Asc order in data table

Tags: php, datatable, datatables

JavaScript code:

```
$('document').ready(function() {            
   $('#payment_detailsview').dataTable({

    "oLanguage": {
    "oPaginate": {
      "sPrevious": "",
      "sNext": ""

    }
    },
    "iDisplayLength": 25,
    "pagingType": "full_numbers",
     "bLengthChange": false,
     "order": [[ 2, 'desc' ]],
    "aLengthMenu": [
    [5, 10, 25, 50, -1],
    [5, 10, 25, 50, "All"]
    ],
```

In third colunmn, I had last name but it doesn't support for `"order": [[ 2, 'desc' ]]`. What should I do?

Comment: show your html please!

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to me. The only thing I can see is to change the 2 to a 1:

```
"order": [[ 1, 'desc' ]],
```

since the index starts at 0 your second column will be 1. use desc or asc

Comment: yeah got it but no responce for character. i have tried  "aaSorting": [[ 0, 'desc' ]],  instead of "order": [[ 1, 'desc' ]],...?????